# New Android Project with Eclipse (Explanation of the Code)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to programming Android. When I start a new Android Application Project in Eclipse it automatically opens 2 files for me:

MainActivity.java and fragment_main.xml

```
package com.example.testprogram;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testprogram.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I wonder what all this stuff is. The Tutorials I watch always have a different code when they start a new project. For example the .xml file that Eclipse opens for them is named activity_main.xml (unlike mine which is named fragment_main.xml). Also their MainActivity.java has less methods integrated then mine.

Can Someone tell me wether that makes a huge difference and how i can maybe change that.

Comment: You need to do the basics first. developer.android.com has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You are using latest one so it get like this. Don't worry about it.

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

instead  of

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

Remove all code in your MainActivity except `OnCreate()`. Then you follow your tutorial.

You onCreate should be

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are probably old tutorials (on Android platform even after couple of months an tutorial can become old), Android ADT is constantly changing. It now automatically adds an `Activity` and a `Fragment` to your project. Instead of just an `Activity`. You can still use knowledge from those tutorials and fit it into `Fragments`. Or delete `Fragments` and use only `Activities`. But Android is promoting the use of `Fragments` with `Activities`, not just mere `Activities` so you should learn how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Create New Project Like This:

Start `File->New->Android Application Project->Next->Next->Next->Select-> Empty Activity->Next->Finish